# Count the number of network packets in realtime (CLI)

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I want to count the number of network incoming/outgoing packets in realtime and in the CLI (I want to use the count to write shell script)

I try to use 'tcpdump' and 'tsahrk' combined with pipeline, but it's doesn't work (I have little talent and learning).

Finally,I found the command 'dumpcap', it's almost close to my need, here is dumpcap stdout

```
[root@hostname ~]# dumpcap -i eth0
File: /tmp/wiresharkXXXXuTE8mU
Packets: 31
```

When i use this command combined with 'grep', like this 'dumpcap -i eth0 | grep -o '[0-9]*' to filter the number in stdout(31),but it's still doesn't work.

Is their any way to solve this or any idea for this ??

**Thank you very much for your attention to this matter.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A packet capture program such as tcpdump, TShark, or dumpcap will probably put the interface into promiscuous mode, which means more packets will show up than would show up under normal circumstances.

The count in dumpcap goes to the standard error, not the standard output.

Dumpcap will write the packets to the file in question, which you may or may not want; if you have a lot of traffic, that file will keep getting bigger and bigger and take up more space on the file system /tmp is on.

You probably want to consider some tool that just gets statistics from the regular networking stack, such as ifconfig on Linux or netstat on various OSes:

```
$ netstat -w 1 -I en0
            input          (en0)           output
   packets  errs      bytes    packets  errs      bytes colls
         0     0          0          0     0          0     0
         0     0          0          0     0          0     0
         1     0         98          1     0         98     0
         1     0         98          1     0         98     0

                      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following output on my computer:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep RX
      RX packets:113995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      RX bytes:62022831 (62.0 MB)  TX bytes:11453699 (11.4 MB)
```

I can do the following to retrieve the number of RX packets:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "RX packets" | tr ":" " " | awk '{print $3}'
113995
```

Unfortunately it is not quite clear what exactly it is that you need. What do you mean by "count the number of packets in realtime"? Do you want a counter to be incremented and the value of the counter reported whenever a packet is seen? Or do you simply wish to count how many packets were seen within a given time period? Also what is the ultimate goal of your shell script?